# Convert words to date

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion

Okay, I am trying to figure out how to turn words like:

```
Sun-Mar-5-2017
```

Into a number date format like:

```
03052017
```

All I know to do is turn numbers into words but not the other way around tho.
So, is it possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you already tried moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: A simple parse and format function is perhaps 4 lines of code, what have you tried?

Comment: no coz some of moment js params are... weird... well, at least with what i'm working with so far. and i've tried `date.parse` and... it ended weird :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is my solution but you can consider Jeremy Jackson's as better.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var dateSplited = date.split("-");

  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var day = dateSplited[2];
    if (day < 10){
    day = "0" + day;
  }  
  var month = monthNames.indexOf(dateSplited[1]) + 1;
    if (month < 10){
    month = "0" + month;
  }  
  var year = dateSplited[3];

  return month + day + year;
}

alert(formatDate("Sun-Mar-5-2017"));
```

Comment: Re "*… consider Jeremy Jackson's as better.*" no, I don't. ;-)

Comment: Well, if my answer is right for you then mark it as answer with the green tick. Otherwise mark any other answer or give more intel how can we help you.

Comment: This is the only one that somehow worked for me. Thanks dude! :D coz moment.js ended weird somehow. it may have been because of some of the params i was working on :/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that can be done:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var dd = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
    var MM = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    // create the format you want
    return (MM + "" + dd + "" + yyyy);
}

var dateString = 'Sun-Mar-5-2017';
var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
var newDateString = formatDate(dateObj);
```

Comment: `new Date('Sun-Mar-5-2017')` returns an invalid date in Firefox and IE (at least). You should not parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse).

Answer (score 0):

Moment.JS will be easy case in here.

```
var inputDate = 'Sun-Mar-5-2017',
    outDate;

// replace '-' with space ' ' to have proper date string 
inputDate = inputDate.replace(/-/g, ' ');

outDate = moment(inputDate).format('MMDDYYYY'); //"03052017"
```

Comment: yeah but it's somehow heavy. and i can't affort to make my program too heavy

Comment: what do you mean too heavy ? could you please explain ?

Comment: yeah. some of the params that moment.js is using, I am also using, therefore renders differently and lags up my application. :/ it was really weird.

Comment: well that's some other issue in your code, this is pretty simple and easiest solution to your problem as moment could have been handy in other places of our app with date manipulation and it's just few kbs in size which is great to have

Comment: but if you don't have to use all those codes then they would be considered as idle or trash codes :/ therefore could potentially slow down other code rendering and whatnot.